# \pagebreak unexpected behavior: a break too much

Tags: page-breaking

I am working on a large document, `memoir` class, compiled with LuaLaTeX (TL 2023). The document is too large and complex to allow me to post a MWE, so I'm just asking for some guess or indications, what should I look for in my log, or any other clue that could be useful to solve the problem.

I want to get rid of an orphan line, so I inserted a `\pagebreak[4]` where you see the blue arrow on page 67:

[image]

As you can see, it works properly, but it inserts also a second undesired page break. Here the image of pages 68 (again) and 69:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` before "La experiencia mariana..."

Comment: Thanks @SimonDispa . But if I add `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}`, the page will be shorter, i.e. the footnotes will go over. Instead, I'd like to have more `\skip\footins` space, but the notes in the same position. I've tried to add a considerable amount to `\skip\footins`, but this does not fix the problem of the second (unwanted) pagebreak... Of course, I can live with an `enlargethispage`; but I'm also curios if this behavior of `\pagebreak` can be explained...

Comment: `\pagebreak` only adds one penalty (in a vadjust if (as i think you did here) you add it in horizontal mode, so it can't force two page breaks. If you get twobreaks something else is happening, you need to make an example, or at least show that part of your code

Comment: `\pagebreak` in h mode forces a page break after the line on which the node appears. Are you sure you did not add it too late? add it after Dios,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I cannot share the code, but your indication helped me. I guess it's just a complicated puzzle of footnotes and widows/orphans, so that the compiler has no better thing to do  than adding the second pagebreak. I will fix the problem another way.

Comment: If you've add the `\pagebreak` after the word space, try adding it before (or even before one or more other words in that line).

Comment: You don't need to share your actual code. You just need dummy text which reproduces the problem.